# same string in multiple while loops not resolved

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean-logic

The logic I'm trying to construct is when the user collects four total affiliates, the console will print that they've reached four but they can still go on if they choose to.

If they decide to stop at four, they should type "quit". The problem rises at the second while loop with the if else statements. I get the error "aff cannot be resolved".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Seption {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome back!");    

        Scanner userName = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Username: ");
        String username = userName.next();

        Scanner passWord = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Password: ");
        String password = passWord.next();

        int affCount = 0;

        while (affCount <= 4) {

            Scanner newAff = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter new affiliate");
            String aff = newAff.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Alright, " + aff + " is now your new affiliate!");

            affCount = affCount + 1;
            System.out.println("You now have " + affCount + " affiliates");

            if (affCount == 4) {

                System.out.println("Congratulations! You've accumulated 4 affiliates!"
                    + " any new affiliates added to this branch will be extra earnings"
                    + " You can also make a new branch and start over"
                    + " To quit this branch, Type 'quit'");

            continue;
            }
        }

        while (affCount > 4) {

            if (aff.equals("quit") == false) {

                Scanner newAff = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("enter new affiliate");
                String aff = newAff.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Alright, " + aff + " is now your new affiliate!");

                affCount = affCount + 1;
                System.out.println("You now have " + affCount + " affiliates");

            }

            else if (aff.equals("quit")) {

                System.out.println("This branch is now over");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's out of scope. You need to declare `aff` outside the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just create an instance of the `Scanner` from `System.in` once and use that same instance anywhere that you need to get an input from the user:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("Welcome back!");    
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Username: "); String   
username = scanner.next();  
System.out.println("Password: "); 
String password = scanner.next(); 
int affCount = 0; 
String aff = "";
while (affCount <= 4) { 
    System.out.println("enter new affiliate");     
     aff = scanner.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("Alright, " + aff + " is now your new affiliate!"); 
     affCount = affCount + 1; 
     System.out.println("You now have " + affCount + " affiliates"); 
     if (affCount == 4) 
        { 
         System.out.println("Congratulations! You've accumulated 4 affiliates!" + " any new affiliates added to this branch will be extra earnings" + " You can also make a new branch and start over" + " To quit this branch, Type 'quit'");
        continue; 
        }
    } 

    while (affCount > 4) { 
         if (aff.equals("quit") == false) 
             { 
              System.out.println("enter new affiliate"); 
              aff = scanner.nextLine(); 
              System.out.println("Alright, " + aff + " is now your new affiliate!"); 
              affCount = affCount + 1; 
              System.out.println("You now have " + affCount + " affiliates"); 
               } 
           else if (aff.equals("quit")) 
                   { 
                   System.out.println("This branch is now over");
                   break; }
           } 
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I inputted the corrections but now it gives me the error "Local variable aff may not have been initialized". This only shows up for the if else statements in the last while loop.

Comment: Yeah, apparently someone suggested an edit to my answer and changed the code. When you instantiate `aff` initialize it: `String aff = ""`... The answer should be fixed now!!